# ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, tomcat, aspectj

I am working on Hibernate3 Spring3 project starter with Tomcat 7,

I am struggling with this ClassNotFoundException - of aopalliance interceptor Jar (is this AspectJ??)

This despite the fact that the Jar exist is in the class-path.

What I don't understand from maven is, where do I use this Jar - who is dependent on this Jar?

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
```

Here is the problematic jar:

```
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile


[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
...
```

Comment: publish exception please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who is dependent on this Jar?

The Spring framework needs it for Spring AOP. Stand-alone AspectJ does not need it.